# How to calculate offset line

Tags: assembly, disassembly

I want to inject x-code into the PE header (for the sake of experience) that outputs the string to the console.
I almost reached my goal, there was only one touch left...
I want to put offset of the string I want to output to the dx register.
I've already been able to put the line itself in .data section.data section.
I don't understand how to specify an offset, or rather calculate it
(I work in the hiew program)

Everything I tried didn't help me much.

Comment: Probably the simplest is to use a relative address. Examine the headers to determine the offset between the code and the data sections. Compensate for the known offsets of your code and your string relative to their respective sections.

Comment: Even simpler if you embed the string next to your code or create it on the stack at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention putting the address into the dx register, I assume you are on 64 bit windows and want to use `WriteFile` which happens to take the buffer address in `rdx`.

Although you say you already have the string in the .data section it is actually simplest to put it into the .text section beside your code and use rip relative addressing:

```
lea rdx, [rel string]
call WriteFile
call ExitProcess
string: db "Hello world!", 10, 13
```

(nasm syntax, and I assume you have the other arguments and the stack layout already taken care of). The `lea rdx, [rel string]` in this case produces the machine code `48 8D 15 0A 00 00 00` since the offset to the string is 10 bytes from the start of the following instruction.

If you instead want to have your string in the data section, proceed as follows:

1. Determine base address of .data from headers, e.g. `address_of_data = 0x403000`
2. Determine base address of .text from headers, e.g. `address_of_text = 0x401000`
3. Determine file offset of .data from headers, e.g. `file_offset_of_data = 0x2400`
4. Determine file offset of .text from headers, e.g. `file_offset_of_text = 0x0600`
5. Calculate virtual address of string by doing `file_offset_of_string - file_offset_of_data + address_of_data` e.g. `address_of_string = 0x2410 - 0x2400 + 0x403000 = 0x403010`
6. Calculate address of the `lea` instruction by doing `file_offset_of_lea - file_offset_of_text + address_of_text`, e.g. `address_of_lea = 0x0bcf - 0x600 + 0x401000 = 0x4015cf`
7. Calculate the rip relative offset by doing `address_of_string - address_of_lea - size_of_lea`, e.g. `0x403010 - 4015cf - 7 = 0x1a3a`

This is what you need to put into the `lea`, e.g. `48 8D 15 3a 1a 00 00`.

Comment: thx, useful information